# nest helper methods in rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested, helper, helpermethods

I would to nest some helper methods to simplify my application_helper, for example I have a bunch of methods dealing with currencies which apply for the entire app and I would like to put in the currencies_helper and then simply include that entire helper into the application helper.

How can I do this?

I tried:

```
helper :currencies
```

and got

```
undefined method `helper' for ApplicationHelper:Module
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Helpers in rails are just modules which get included in controllers to help share functionality between them.  There's been some weirdness around helpers in rails 3, so depending on what version you're running things may or may not work as you expect out the box.

Essentially what you want to do is add `helper :all` to your `application_controller` which will include ALL helpers in ALL your controllers.  If this isn't what you want you can specify the specific helpers you want `helper :currencies` for example.

In the rails 3 betas `helper :all` was the default behavior, but I *think* they've reverted that in the latest release.

There's a [great article](http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2007/2/26/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-quick-way-to-include-all-helpers-in-your-controllers) that discusses how this works in rails 2, but there may be differences in rails 3, but it should be a good starting point.

Comment: ah, for some reason I was putting it into the ApplicationHelper method instead of the controller, now it works.